# Using .withColumn on all remaining columns in DF

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I want to anonymize or replace almost all columns in a pyspark dataframe except a few ones.

I know its possible to do something like:

```py
anonymized_df = employee_df.withColumn("EMPLOYEENUMBER", col("EMPLOYEENUMBER"))\
                                        .withColumn("NAME1", lit(""))\
                                        .withColumn("TELEPHONE", lit(""))\
                                        .withColumn("ELECTRONICMAILADDRESS", lit(""))
```

However, doing this for all columns is a tedious process. I would rather want to do something along the lines of this:

```py
anonymized_df = employee_df.withColumn("EMPLOYEENUMBER", col("EMPLOYEENUMBER"))\
                           .withcolumn("*", lit("")) # all other columns replace
```

This does however not seem to work. Is there other work arounds that achieve this?

I guess one solution would be to could create a list of column names and do something along the lines of:

```py
col_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6']

for col in col_list:
   employee_df= employee_df.withColumn(col, lit("")))
```

Other suggestions would be of much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `select`. syntax-wise it won't be much different but it will only create 1 snapshot.

```py
keep_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
empty_cols = ['d', 'e', 'f'] # or list(set(df.columns) - set(keep_cols))

df = df.select(*keep_cols, *[lit('').alias(x) for x in empty_cols])
```

Comment: could you illustrate your thought behind list(set(df.columns) - set(keep_cols))? I feel the order of the columns in the new _df must be intact as I have to write it back to replace the existing table (with mode overwrite)

Comment: that is for easiness when you don't care about the column order.  if you care about the order, you can use list comprehension.